# Why won't KochCurve.exe run on Wine?

Tags: windows, wine

I have simple program KochCurve.exe. It is a DOS based program which asks for some input and displays the Koch Curve while executed in windows.

On Ubuntu i installed WINE and also configured using wineconfig. I have set the permissions for "Allow executing file as program".

When i run this .exe it shows DOS like window for a while and gets suddenly closed.

Help please.

Comment: Are you sure this program is supported in WINE? Not all programs run in Wine. You should check WineHQ. If this program is rated "garbage" or "bronze" it probably won't work.

Comment: Originally it was C code. It is converted into .exe (I don't know how). It runs on windows.

Comment: Try to run it from a Terminal window eg. `wine KochCurve.exe` and see if there is any error output. Update the question with the resulting messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running it in a [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) instead.

Seems like an easier solution than to attempt to run it in Wine.

Answer (score 2):

This  [tutorial](http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=464&sid=c6da1d319bb6a8768a8bdfc51417bf1d) from the Wine Forums will guide you on how to run a DOS program using wine.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance, or even forever: Your post would be useless to someone having the problem outlined here.

Answer (score 2):

Please run the program from terminal (`wineconsole myprogram.exe`). I don't think it's really a DOS program but rather a .Net or Mono program. In that case it will tell you that it's not a DOS program and has to be run from Windows. That's the error message you probably can't see because the window instantly closes. All .Net and Mono programs contain this mini DOS program code, which really is a program that can be run from a DOS operating system.

Install mono and run the program from terminal with: `mono myprogram.exe`

Please don't mix up the terminology:

- DOS = an old [CP/M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) based operating system
- [DOSBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosbox) = an emulator mostly for games written for MS DOS
- Program with no GUI = a program meant to be run from command line/[console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_console)/terminal, doesn't have to be a DOS program even if it has the extension `.exe`